# How to add tasks to celery queue?

Tags: python, celery

I've a JSON format string.

```
[{"from":"9871098", "to": " 123455", "message" : "Hello World"}, {"from":"9871098", "to": " 123455", "message" : "Hello World"}, {"from":"9871098", "to": " 123455", "message" : "Hello World"}, {"from":"9871098", "to": " 123455", "message" : "Hello World"}]
```

I want to add each entry to the queue after every 5 secs and then process each message accordingly. How will I do that?

Here is my incomplete code. How will I go about it?

```
from celery import Celery
import json
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def data_pusher():
    message_file = json.loads("/Desktop/file.json")
    for data in message_file:
```

Comment: Have you read the [tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#next-steps=)?

Answer (score -1):

Not the ideal way of doing it, but it should just work fine:

```
from celery import Celery
import json
from time import sleep
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def data_pusher():
    message_file = json.loads("/Desktop/file.json")
    for data in message_file:
        // add the data line to the queue
        sleep(5)
```